# Supermercado en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> 10.3. Un pequeño supermercado dispone en la salida de tres cajas de pago.
> En el local hay 25 carritos de compra. Escribir un programa que simule el funcionamiento, siguiendo las siguientes reglas:
>
> - Si cuando llega un cliente no hay ningún carrito disponible, espera a que lo haya.
> - Ningún cliente se impacienta y abandona el supermercado sin pasar por alguna de las colas de las cajas.
> - Cuando un cliente finaliza su compra, se coloca en la cola de la caja que hay menos gente. y no se cambia de cola.
> - En el momento en que un cliente paga en la caja, su carrito de la compra queda disponible.

Ocupo realizar el problema que se ve en la imagen pero hasta el momento lo único que he logrado es que se tome un número de la lista del carro y se asigne a la lista de la caja pero no sé cómo hacer que se devuelva una vez que se termina la transacción, y que al ingresar más clientes, se espere a que se desocupen carritos.

```
class Supermarket:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cart = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        self.fisrtcheckout = []
        self.secondcheckout = []
        self.thirdcheckout = []
        self.client = []
        

    def Till(self):
        for x in self.cart:
            self.fisrtcheckout.append(self.cart.pop(0))
        for y in self.cart:
            self.secondcheckout.append(self.cart.pop(0))
        for i in self.cart:
            self.thirdcheckout.append(self.cart.pop(0))
        print(self.fisrtcheckout)
        print(self.cart)
        print(self.secondcheckout)
        print(self.cart)
        print(self.thirdcheckout)
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que lo piden en Python? ¿No será que lo piden en C?

Comment: Lo encontré, un PDF que lo hacen todo en Java, no es Python... En la página 313 y agrega un punto adicional... `Representar la lista de carritos de la compra y las cajas de salida mediante colas.`

Comment: Si debe ser en Phyton, ya que en la clase solo ese lenguaje estamos viendo.

Comment: No sé si tendrás el libro, pero veo que en la página 312 arriba dice __Estructuras de datos en Java__, es decir, el lenguaje es Java ahí.

Comment: Si ya vi el libro gracias, mi profesor tomo el problema de el libro pero se ocupa implementar en Python, ademas no logre encontrar las respuestas del libro entonces no me puedo guiar con eso tampoco.

Comment: No entiendo a qué se refiere con _transacción_. ¿En qué parte del código está eso? Además, no veo que en el código se ingresen clientes.

Comment: Hay libros como **Banks: Discrete-Event System Simulation** que si bien desarrollan los ejemplos con Java... nada impide que estos puedan ser Resueltos con Excel, Arena (Rockwell Software), Matlab, Lua o incluso Python... Pero sí considero que la pregunta debería ser más especifica... sobre qué parte del modelado del sistema está teniendo dificultades al momento de ser implementado... porque puede dar la impresión de que se trata _¡ey comunidad! resuelvan mi trabajo..._ En todo caso sugiero que veas este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJyf8Q0KLRY) (inglés) sobre el particular.